# How do I display a row of random numbers in C# instead of a column?

Tags: c#, output

Here is the program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplicationlotto
{
    class Program
    {
        const int LIMIT = 7;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] lotto = new int[LIMIT];
            int lotDigits;

            Random rnd = new Random();

            foreach (int sub in lotto)
            {
                lotDigits = rnd.Next(0, 8);
                Console.WriteLine(lotDigits);

            }


        }
    }
}
```

I want it to display 7 random digits in a row forming a 7 digit "lotto number", so it would look like "5902228" instead of:

5

9

0

2

2

2

8

I tried using "0:D7" and it gives me a bunch of zeroes with the last few digits being other numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Console.Write` instead of `Console.WriteLine`

Answer (score 2):

You should create your expected `string` before `WriteLine`, below is to use LINQ `Enumerable.Range` and `string.Join` with fewer code lines:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var random = new Random();
    var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 7)
                            .Select(x => random.Next(0, 9));

    var output = string.Join(string.Empty, numbers);

    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Or use `Aggregate`:

```
var output = Enumerable.Range(0, 7)
                       .Aggregate(string.Empty, 
                               (str, i) => str += random.Next(0, 9));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `Console.Write` in place of  `Console.WriteLine`

`Console.WriteLine` - add a extra line to the console window, hence each numbers appear in different line.

```
foreach (int sub in lotto)
{
    lotDigits = rnd.Next(0, 8);
    Console.Write(string.Format("{0}\t", lotDigits));
}
```

#### You should separate the number so that they dont seems be as one individual number.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (int sub in lotto)
{
        lotDigits = rnd.Next(0, 8);
        Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", lotDigits));
}
```